# PHP SoapClient SSL connection timeout error

Tags: php, web-services, soap, ssl, https

While initiating a PHP SOAP client webservice I get these errors in production.

Here is the line of code which generates the error:

```
//the php soap server is at different server
$client = new SoapClient(SITE_ROOT . "locally hosted wsdl",
                         array("trace" => 1, "exception" => 1));
```

The error being generated is:

```
ERRNO: 2 \nTEXT: SoapClient::__doRequest() [<a href='soapclient.--dorequest'>soapclient.--dorequest</a>]: SSL: connection timeout \nLOCATION:
```

So these errors only occur in production and occur 2-3 % of the total requests.

Also this is a PHP SOAP over HTTPS webservice, also the server hosting the webservice has firewall but all our frontend servers have access through the firewall.

Also the `default_socket_timeout` is set to 60 secs and max execution time is 30 seconds.

My question:

I want to know why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $client=new SoapClient(
        SITE_ROOT."your/wsdl.here.wsdl",
        array(
            "exceptions" => true, 

            "connection_timeout" => 60,

            "style" => SOAP_RPC, 
            "use" => SOAP_ENCODED, 
        )
    );

    $mxResponse=$client->__soapCall(
        "someFunctionName", 
        array("params", "here")
    );
```